# C++ std::cin make a placeholder

Tags: c++, user-input, cin

In HTML one can have an user input element like this:

```
<input type="text" value="Mickey">
```

which has a default value the user can edit. I'm wondering whether it is possible to implement something similar for `std::cin` where the user can modify or edit the default value in-place.

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're asking about. Could you at least give a pseudo-code sample of what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I think he means a "default value" that would be read if you just pressed enter, but would be overwritten when you start typing.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean "default value" so the user just has to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> simply use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read input. If the input line is empty use the default value.

Simple and stupid example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    static std::string const default_name = "Foobar";
    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Please give you name (default " << default_name << "): ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);

    if (name.empty())
        name = default_name;

    std::cout << "You name is " << name << '\n';
}
```

If no "name" is given for the question, the name will be set to the "default name".

Comment: No because i want that the user can see the default value, and modify it

Comment: @Olivier.B Then you want system-dependent editing capabilities, it's not possible to do something like that using plain standard C++. On a POSIX system (like Linux or OSX) you should look into the readline library, or possibly ncurses. Optionally you might want to look into creating a GUI (Graphical User Interface) program where things like that are easy (but getting it going is hard for a beginner)